# Why bootstrap.css messes up my shiny app?

Tags: html, r, css, shiny

How can I basically change my sidebarPanel background color to white without messing up with my style? When I am using the bootstrap.css I downloaded from bootswatch and place it in www folder in my app folder, it changes the style to some really badly positioned buttons. So here's what I have without CSS:
[image]

And here's what I have with [CSS](http://bootswatch.com/journal/bootstrap.min.css):
[image]

As you see the alignment of radioButtons gets messed up using CSS.

Any solution how to make the CSS work?
Or how to make the background (only in the sidebarPanel white without messing up with the CSS(no CSS)?

Comment: You given css is mess up. And can't understandable.  can you create fiddle?

Comment: This is not a CSS written by me. It is from bootswatch website and people use it often for bootstrapping

Comment: Yes there are lots of css used for radio button.

Comment: Can you add your sidebarPanel HTML code to the question?

Comment: Please post your HTML code and  CSS.